# How to get this Javascript anagram algorithm to work in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, anagram

In my studies of all things algorithms and data structures, I'm trying to do in Ruby what I learn using Javascript. Both languages have their own way of hoisting variables and dealing with truthy/falsey.

This algo works fine in JS but in Ruby I'm getting the classic `undefined method`+' for nil:NilClass` when running a ternary on the existence of a Hash.

I've tried to do some conditionals beforehand to make sure nothing will pass if the object doesn't exist.

Here's the Javascript solution:

```
function validAnagram(str1, str2){
    if (str1.length !== str2.length) {
        return false;
    }
  const strOneObj = {};
  const strTwoObj = {}; 

  for (let char of str1) {
      strOneObj[char] = strOneObj[char] + 1 || 1;
    }
   for (let char of str2) {
       strTwoObj[char] = strTwoObj[char] + 1 || 1;
   } 

  for (let values in strOneObj) {
    if (strOneObj[values] !== strTwoObj[values]) {
      return false; 
    }
    return true; 
  }

}

validAnagram('cinema', 'ice')
```

Here's the Ruby version:

```
def valid_anagram(str1, str2)
  if str1.length != str2.length 
    false 
  else 
    str_one_hash = {}
    str_two_hash = {}

    str1.split('').each do |char|
      if str_one_hash == nil 
        str_one_hash[char] = 0 
      else 
        str_one_hash[char] += 1
      end 

    (str_one_hash.keys & str_one_hash.keys).each do |char, count| 
      if str_one_hash[char] != str_one_hash[char]
        false
      end 
    end 
  end   
    true 
end 

valid_anagram("cinema", "iceman")
```

In short: How do I get this working in beautiful Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close.

`if str_one_hash == nil` is the culprit.

`if str_one_hash[char] == nil` is what you're looking for.

Note: You can set the default value of your hash to 0 by calling `str_one_hash = Hash.new { 0 }` — eliminating the nil check.

Answer (score 2):

A ruby way of doing this

```
def valid_anagram(str1, str2)
  if str1.length != str2.length 
    false 
  else 
    str_one_hash = str1.split('').map{|char| [char, str1.count(char)]}.to_h
    str_two_hash = str2.split('').map{|char| [char, str2.count(char)]}.to_h
    str_one_hash == str_two_hash
  end   
end
```